# " Modding" by normal closure in group Z \ -5.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

You can mod a group by a normal closure instead of relations, to use a group, but how does the process ' work '? I am supposed to be learning about presenting a group, except with this here example ' ' whenever relations are not a subgroup thus we ought to use normal closure ' '. Again I kind of want the example to look like ' integers \ $- \; 5$, modulo $5$. Because then, you have to use $\textit{normal closure}$ and I can't even tell what anyof this looks like - as $\{ -t \, , \; 5 \; , \, t\}$ evidently maps to 0 and relator =5 does. 
In short, how does "$\textit{modular arithmetic}$" really work by normal closure??? The normal closure and the relators map to 0? Maybe an entirely new description is ok for an answer instead of what I'm telling you just as the only example I really know of like this is $Z/Z$ which is  again 0....

Comment: I've read this several times, and I'm still not sure what the question is....

Comment: Okay. Im thinking " why does the normal closure seem to map to 0 along with the relators when that is not the goal "?

Comment: That is, if Z maps to 0 in Z / Z, and 5z maps to 0 in Z/5Z, then subsets of Z which are the normal closure N also must be sent to 0 in Z / N or Fs/N [ N is the normal closure and Z is my example of a free set over S].

Comment: Let me know if that makes anything clearer 4 the question okay... otherwise, thanks for trying....

Comment: The integers under addition is an abelian group so the normal closure of any subgroup is just the same as the subgroup itself. So in a sense taking the normal closure of a subgroup in an abelian group does nothing.